# How to merge the boundaries of two figure having very close boundary?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have digitized the states of India and collected the coordinates of the boundaries.
Let us say, two states S1 and S2 have a common boundary.

When I acquired the coordinates of that boundary ( manually), I am getting two different boundaries. One for S1 and the other for S2. Now, **I want to merge the boundaries, so that there is only 1 boundary visible.** **Is there any command for that?***NOTE: I am using the following command to fill the colors*     >>>fill(Xcoordinates,Ycoordinates,color)

Comment: More details maybe ? What do you mean with "manually" ? Why do you want to modify the drawing only, not the actual values of the coordinates ? I would run a loop on all Xcoordinates of S1 and try to find corresponding X/Ycoordinates that are close enough in S2 (below a threshold), and then merge the points.

Comment: Manually means, I clicked on the boundary to acquire the data. Now while doing this, I am not able to get the exact boundary points. that's why there are 2 boundaries visible.

Merging the X coordinates and Y coordinates separately will not work. I need to find the points which are very close to each other and then merge them. Take the average maybe.

Comment: Yes, this is why I said "below a threshold" : in the loop (index i) on every Xcoordinate for S1 (call it X1(i) as in the answer below), you search every value in X2 that are "close enough to X1(i)". For that you calculate in a loop (index j) the distance between the points defined by X1(i),Y1(i) and X2(j),Y2(j). If this distance is small enough, then you can merge the points and change the values in X1,Y1,X2,Y2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you have two sets of boundaries S1 and S2.  Each consisting of a set of co-ordinates S1 = {X1,Y1} and  S2 = {X2,Y2}. where S1 is not equal to S2.

You would like to merge these two sets of boundaries into a 3rd set S3 that is an approximation of the real boundary given S1 and S2.

Under the assumption the two sets are fairly close and don't have outliers,
by far the simplest way would be to take the average of S1 and S2.

In Matlab you do that like this:

```
   X3 = [X1;X2];
   Y3 = [Y1;Y2];
   X3 = mean(X3);
   Y3 = mean(Y3);
   fill(X3,Y3,color);
```

If the assumption is too strong then randomization my be you friend:

option 1: randomly chose either S1 or S2!

option 2: randomly choose x and y from each pair of co-ordinates to form a new co-ordinate X3,Y3.

option 3: Randomly choose the first co-ordinate, then greedily add the nearest x and y from the next coordinate in the list, and so one, until no coordinates are left. (assuming they are ordered)

run a few times until it looks peachy!

EDIT:  It turns out that I DID NOT understand the question correctly! S1 and S2 are not complete boundaries from different sources, they are boundaries of different states, this answer is not useful for that case.

EDIT:  First find the disagreeing points for S1 and S2 then the problem reduces back to how i thought it was before, with S1' and S2'.  however thy are still not same size and order, so i can't just average them.

option 1:  randomly pick one

```
    close all
    clear all
    load('X1.mat');



    plot(X1,Y1,'color', 'red');
    hold on
    plot(X2,Y2,'color', 'blue');



    %sorry need to rescale to use poly mask;
    maxS  = max([ max(X1),max(Y1),max(X2),max(Y2) ]);
    minS =  min([ min(X1),min(Y1),min(X2),min(Y2) ]);

    tagetMax = 1000;
    scaled_X1 =(X1-minS);
    scaled_X1 = (tagetMax*scaled_X1);
    scaled_Y1 =(Y1-minS);
    scaled_Y1 = (tagetMax*scaled_Y1);
    scaled_X2 =(X2-minS);
    scaled_X2 = (tagetMax*scaled_X2);
    scaled_Y2 =(Y2-minS);
    scaled_Y2 = (tagetMax*scaled_Y2);

    scaled_X1 =  round(scaled_X1);
    scaled_X2 =  round(scaled_X2);
    scaled_Y1 =  round(scaled_Y1);
    scaled_Y2 =  round(scaled_Y2);

    %make a mask
    S1_mask = poly2mask(scaled_X1,scaled_Y1,tagetMax,tagetMax);
    S2_mask = poly2mask(scaled_X2,scaled_Y2,tagetMax,tagetMax);
    %make a bit bigger
    S1_mask = imdilate(S1_mask,strel('square',10));
    S2_mask = imdilate(S2_mask,strel('square',10));


    %find intersection
    S_intersection = S1_mask & S2_mask;
    [y,x] =  find(S_intersection);

    %find points in intersection
    scaled_S31 = [scaled_X1;scaled_Y1]';
    XY = [x,y];
    [S3_xy1, Locb1] = ismember(scaled_S31,XY,'rows');

    scaled_S32 = [scaled_X2;scaled_Y2]';
    XY = [x,y];
    [S3_xy2, Locb2] = ismember(scaled_S32,XY,'rows');


    S3_x1 = X1(S3_xy1); % the offending x's from S1
    S3_y1 = Y1(S3_xy1); % the offending y's from S1
    S3_x2 = X2(S3_xy2); % the offending x's from S2
    S3_y2 = Y2(S3_xy2); % the offending y's from S2

    plot(S3_x1,S3_y1,'color','green')
    plot(S3_x2,S3_y2,'color','green')


    %solution 1:
    %randomly pick S1 or S2
    S1C = [S3_x1;S3_y1]';
    S2C = [S3_x2;S3_y2]';
    SC = {S1C, S2C};

    s = randi([1,2],1);
    S3 = SC{s};
    plot(S3(:,1),S3(:,2),'color','cyan')
```

Comment: You are just taking the average of two coordinates. That is not what I want.
See, I want to merge the points which are close to each other.

Please see the figure. In the fig, you can see that there are 2 boundaries visible, and I need only 1. I had am image file. I opened it and acquired the coordinates of the boundaries.

Now when I plot it, it should look like the image itself. But 2 boundaries are visible. because I acquired the coordinates of S1 and S2 separately. So, human error.

Also the size of each array containing the coordinates are different. So X3 =  [X1; X2] wont work.

Comment: okay, so lets say both S1 and S2 are in order and are the same length, in that case would the average be suitable?  if that is not the case then sorry i misunderstand your question.

Comment: OK. I am uploading 4 files. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1Mm17sejxBtWEx1WHp1NFdrbXM&usp=sharing.    Plot X1 vs Y1 and X2 vs Y2 on the same figure. You will see the two boundaries. Tell me how to merge them.

Comment: okay i see from the data that i incorrectly parsed your question, sorry. I thought that the whole map was labelled by two different people giving s1 and s2, rather than s1 and s2 being 2 states, my bad.

Comment: @Tanuj i updated to find the problem region then random choose one.  But once you have that problem points you may try other things.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew about "mask".

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think the best would be to rewrite the part of the code where you defined the boundaries of the states. Actually, it would be easier to define boundaries not as a "closed polygon around a state", but rather "frontier between two surfaces (either two states or one state and another country)".

Then, every state would be associated to a few boundaries, and you would just have to concatenate them when you draw them with the `fill` function (you may need to use `fliplr` in some cases depending on the direction followed when you define each boundary).

You can still follow the tips I gave in the comments to resolve your exact question, but I think it would be easier to come back to the source of your problem : boundaries definition.

If you need more details, you can still show the code that enables you to create the boundaries manually, and we'll see what we can do !

Comment: OK. I am uploading 4 files. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1Mm17sejxBtWEx1WHp1NFdrbXM&usp=sharing. Plot X1 vs Y1 and X2 vs Y2 on the same figure. You will see the two boundaries. Tell me how to merge them.